# Avoid double encoding on XML save

Tags: php, xml, encoding

I'm creating a XML file with SimpleXMLElement like this :

```
 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><DonneesDepot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></DonneesDepot>');
```

I insert some data and I save with:

```
$xml->asXML($path);
```

When I save, this automatically encode `&`, `>`, `<`, but I need to encode the quotes, so when I insert my data I use `htmlspecialchars()` :

```
htmlspecialchars($some_data, ENT_XML1 | ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
```

This encode the quotes with `&apos;` but then because of the encoding on saving this encode as `&amp;apos;`,

How can I do to save the file and encoding also the quotes or save the file without any encoding and then I could use `htmlspecialchars()` when I insert my data?